# How does Grub check if a system started successfully?

Tags: linux, grub2, boot-loader

I am testing an automated migration from Windows to Linux using Grub2 on my EFI partition.
My goal is to have a fallback solution in place so when booting from my new Linux image fails, the existing Windows image is loaded. Grub provides this out of the box: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Booting-fallback-systems.html

However, I would like to have some deeper understanding on how exactly Grub checks whether a kernel has been loaded successfully or not. Meaning, I want to know until which point exactly the fallback can be triggered. So how does Grub check if a system started successfully?

E.g. does Grub fallback ensure that the systemd process has been started on my new Linux image?

Comment: I think the failure that refers to is merely something like the files that the entry loads are gone or that the files are not found to be valid ones that grub is able to execute, but not kernel panic or init error whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the document you linked to: the booted system is responsible for resetting the boot configuration.

You just have to apply some common sense: if Grub were responsible for detecting this, that would mean that Grub would need to know how to talk to every Operating System that exists, has existed and even the ones that have not been written yet and check whether it booted successfully. It is clearly infeasible to know about every Operating System ever created, and it is simply impossible to know about Operating Systems that haven't been created yet, so this cannot be how it works.

This should be immediately clear from your suggestion:

> E.g. does Grub fallback ensure that the systemd process has been started on my new Linux image?

If this were true, it would mean that you couldn't boot Linux distributions which don't use systemd. Some Linux distributions use upstart, some use OpenRC, some use runit, some use minit, some use finit, some use sysvinit, some use Epoch, some use s6, some use initng, some use jinit, some use cinit, some use simpleinit, some use twsinit, and sometimes for specific applications, you don't use an init system at all.

Either you wouldn't be able to boot a system which uses any of those, or Grub would have to know about all of those. And that's just the ones for Linux … most BSDs have their own init system, most commercial Unices have their own init system (e.g. SMF on Solaris), and then there's Windows, DOS, and hundreds of other Operating Systems.